# How to pass a built-in function as a callback argument?

Tags: perl

OK, I know that I can always wrap a built-in function in a `sub`:

```
function_taking_callback( sub { return getpwuid( $_[ 0 ] ); } );
```

...but I find it hard to believe that Perl would require this sort of thing.

Comment: `function_taking_callback(sub { getpwuid(@_) });` is shorter.

Comment: @Elyse but not equivalent.

Comment: Use an anonymous sub as a wrapper.  That way if there is an error, you'll get a helpful line number in the stacktrace.

Comment: @Dre: care to elaborate?

Comment: @kjo You got the answer as to why they're not equivalent in your other question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201910/how-can-a-function-pass-all-the-arguments-it-received-transparently-to-another-f )

Comment: @kjo `getpwuid` is prototyped, so `getpwuid(@_)` will pass it the *number of elements* in `@_`, not the value(s) in `@_`.

Comment: @hobbs: sorry, I missed the `@_` in Elyse's form; I thought that the non-equivalence that Dre was referring to had to do with the presence/absence of `return`.

Comment: @kjo nope. You can definitely remove `return` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Perl 5.16 (2012) and newer, you can reference it as `\&CORE::getpwuid` — see the documentation for [CORE](http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html).

On older perls, the `CORE::` syntax exists, but there isn't an actual sub at `CORE::getpwuid` to take a reference to, so your sub wrapper is the best way to go.