# How can a function pass all the arguments it received transparently to another function?

Tags: perl

The title of this post says it all.  The point is that the calling function `X` should be agnostic about the signature of the called function `Y`.  IOW, `X` should just pass to `Y`, *en masse*, all the arguments it (`X`) received, at leave it up to `Y` to complain if the signature is off.

---

I thought this was just a matter of

```
sub X {
  return Y( @_ );
}
```

...but apparently not:

```
sub getpwuid_wrapper {
  return getpwuid( @_ );
}
```

The wrapper above is doing more than merely wrapping:

```
  DB<7> p getpwuid( 5 )
gamesx560games/usr/games/usr/sbin/nologin
  DB<8> p getpwuid_wrapper( 5 )
daemonx11daemon/usr/sbin/usr/sbin/nologin
```

The next bit gives a clue to what may be going on:

```
  DB<9> p getpwuid( 1 )
daemonx11daemon/usr/sbin/usr/sbin/nologin
```

I figure that `getpwuid( @_ )` is getting interpreted as `getpwuid( scalar @_ )`, for reasons beyond my comprehension.

**NOTE:** `getpwuid` is just an example to illustrate the problem.  In practice one needs this sort of pass-through functionality primarily when the function that will be called *is not known until runtime*; e.g. when this function is a callback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because `getpwuid` has a prototype of `$`, which causes it to interpret its parameter in scalar context.

You can see this from the following one-liner:

```
perl -e 'print prototype("CORE::getpwuid"), "\n"'
```

...which prints `$`.

So when you pass `@_` to `getpwuid`, you are correct; it's being taken in scalar context and passing a count of how many elements `@_` contains.

One solution is to use the subroutine form of `goto`, which calls its operand with the same call stack and parameters that were passed to its caller.

Here's an example in the form of a one-liner:

```
perl -e 'print getpwuid(5), "\n"; print sub{ getpwuid(@_) }->(5), "\n"; print sub { goto &CORE::getpwuid }->(5), "\n";'
```

In this example, the first and third calls will pass '5' to `getpwuid`, but the second call will pass `scalar(@_)`, which is `1` in this case.

Another hackish option would be to detect whether the function you are calling has a prototype using the `prototype` function, and react accordingly.  But that's problematic. First, you already know you're calling `getpwuid` -- no need to detect at runtime. And even if you had to detect at runtime for some reason, some `CORE::` functions will return `undef` for their prototype because they use one that cannot be expressed in terms of the prototype options available to us (`system`, for example).

In this specific case since you already know what function you are calling, and already know its prototype, it's probably just easiest to do this:

```
perl -e 'print sub { getpwuid(shift) }->(5), "\n";'
```

**Update:** Where the subroutine being called isn't known until runtime `goto` may be a good means. One of the things you have to look out for with `goto`, however, is that you never return back to the parent sub; the subroutine being gone-to will return directly to the caller of the parent sub.

Another option is to call the target sub with the `&` prefix and no parameters. This also serves to pass `@_` through to it, but in a way that bypasses prototypes.  Here's an example:

```
perl -e 'print sub { &CORE::getpwuid }->(5)'
```

This will appear similar to the `goto` approach, but will not tinker with the call stack, and will return back to the parent sub.

Comment: In practice one needs this sort of thing only when one does **not** know until runtime the function that will be called; e.g., when this function is a callback.  `getpwuid` was just a concrete example to illustrate my point.  Of course, if one knows the function one is calling ahead of time, then the problem of passing arguments to this function in a way that is agnostic its signature becomes an idle academic exercise.  I'll edit my post to make this clearer.

Comment: Since you must make the decision at runtime, use the `prototype` function to introspect, or use goto. Easc has its own problems. Goto will never return to the parent sub, just to the original caller. Prototype will fail for some core functions.

Comment: You can just pass `@_[0..$#_]`, too

Comment: That's also a nice point, @ysth.  :)  A simple solution with no ugly side-effects.